# TypeError when retrieving Google indexes for keywords

Tags: python, indexing

We found this code via Google. It is supposed to give us the Google indexes for the keywords. The problem is that it works for a while then gives us this error:

```
./g1.py size hassize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./g1.py", line 22, in <module>
    n2 = int(gsearch(args[0]+" "+args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math,sys
import json
import urllib

def gsearch(searchfor):
  query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
  url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
  search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
  search_results = search_response.read()
  results = json.loads(search_results)
  data = results['responseData']
  return data

args = sys.argv[1:]
m = 45000000000
if len(args) != 2:
        print "need two words as arguments"
        exit
n0 = int(gsearch(args[0])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n1 = int(gsearch(args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n2 = int(gsearch(args[0]+" "+args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code a few times and found that every once in a while your query returns an object that has `data['responseData'] = None`. This is causing the error you reported. To find out why this is sometimes the case, I output the entire `data` object when `data['responseData'] = None`, and found the following:

```
{u'responseData': None,
 u'responseDetails': u'Suspected Terms of Service Abuse.
                       Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors',
 u'responseStatus': 403}
```

It appears that some of your requests are returning `HTTP 403 Forbidden` status codes, and as a result your query is not being fulfilled (and thus has no data). I would read [the page on Google's Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/errors) and see if you can figure out why some of your requests may be violating its Terms of Service.

Comment: @Yes but what is your best solution I am not doing it too fast I take some break in between too. Any experience on this please share

Comment: Do you mean how should you make the API request or how do you catch the error?

Comment: Yes I mean how to improvise on the API request because I just make 5 or 6 it gives me error any tips on this ?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the the Google API but it sounds to me like you're not supposed to make automated requests.

Comment: So what I should do is manually look them up is it ? This will be very tedious in my case